# What is technically forbidden in the comment?

Tags: bug, comments, word-filter

I have tried to write a comment on regexes:

```
`(-[1-7]|[0-4])`.  `-0` is not a correct expression.
```

And I am getting a strange reaction:

[image]

I have already written on Meta about obviously incorrect automatic text limitations (forbidden use of 'problem' word, even if it is a part of a cited error message) There it could be understood, with a strain. Now it is impossible, sorry.

Comment: It's stripping some the first, second and fourth character and thinks your comment starts with `-1`, which is disallowed (e.g. "-1 because your answer is wrong").

Comment: A little too clever, this comment parser is :)

Comment: And? Why this bug would not be repaired?

Comment: You've only just reported it, bug fixing takes 6-8 weeks :)

Comment: @Stijn Oh, it is absolutely OK. I have understood your explanation that it won't be changed. I understand that in large system changes take time.

Comment: It doesn't need a dev, Shog9 can fiddle with the regex's for those IIRC.

Comment: @Stijn I think, excluding citations from the rule would be enough.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "citations". The code formatting shouldn't matter, because if it did, people would just do `-1`, which I used to see enough of anyway. But the bracket in there *should* be enough to mess it up. Regexes are hard.

Comment: I expect the work-around to be to start with *Shog9 wants me to type some text first* or any other wording to your liking.

Comment: I have already edited the comment, adding the text at the start, thank you. But I am afraid, if there will be somebody that wants to write -1 without arguments, or any negative reaction without arguments, he always can write something as 'That's rubbish. blah-blah', or something as that. And we can't stop it by any regex. Simply any negative reaction without argumentation should be flagged. There is enough enthusiasts here for that.

Comment: @Gangnus: You have to consider where we come from. There was a time where a lot of users posted comments which started with `+1` or `-1`. The mechanism was put in place to tell them that they shouldn't do that. It was never meant to prevent all occurrences of `+1` and `-1`.

Comment: @honk 1. It could happen that that + or -1 at start is a part of a formula. So, it should not be forbidden as such, too. Maybe, only pure +1 or -1.... 2. If "It was never meant to prevent all occurrence of +1 and -1. ", I totally agree. But it seems, that the reality differs from what it was meant, as it happens :-)

Comment: It is a clbuttic regex mistake.

Comment: @gnat It is not. It is the bug report. The bug was very similar, but it is very different, because there was a bug in the 2015 year version and it was repaired and afer the acceptance became too free, and was changed again. That history was ended in 2015 to the common content and was tested. And now it is a bug in the 2017 version.